# Regular expression search with only a portion of a variable

Tags: regex, perl, variables

```
    my $BestMatch = "CGGAGCTTTACGAGCCGTAGCCCAAACA";
    if ($Sequence -~ m/$BestMatch/){
```

Is there a way to modify the regex to only search for the first 6 letters in the $BestMatch sequence? I need to keep the $BestMatch variable in place in the regex, I just need to modify it.
The examples I find online do not make use of a variable, but rather the entire sequence itself. My problem is that the $BestMatch will change for every file opened in a foreach loop, and therefore can't be hardcoded. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like :

```
my$substr = substr($BestMatch,0,6);

if ($Sequence -~ m/\Q$substr/){ 

    # ... whatevs ....

}
```

Of course, if it's just a simple match of strings, you don't need t even use regex; just use [the index() function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html).